# Двери работают странно

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю 2д платформер, захотел двери. По идее должно работать так - есть дверь, и у нее есть `linkeddoor`, при нажатии E пока в двери происходит телепортация на позицию `linkeddoor`.
Вот код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class door : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;

    public move character;
    public Rigidbody2D plr;
    public LayerMask doorlayer;
    public Transform linkeddoor;
    public GameObject doortip;



    void Start()
    {
        doortip.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }



    void Update()
    {
        Collider2D plrcollider = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(plr.position, 0.01f, doorlayer);
        if (plrcollider != null)
        {
            character.canenter = true;
            doortip.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            character.canenter = false;
            doortip.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }



        if (character.entered)
        {
            plr.position = linkeddoor.position;
            character.entered = false;
            character.canenter = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Код с телепортацией при нажатии E(из скрипта персонажа):

```
if (canenter)
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        entered = true;
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что из-за `public` в скрипте, все двери считают один `linkeddoor` своим. Как можно заставить их смотреть только на свой `linkeddoor`?

Comment: Экземпляр linkeddoor задаётся в редакторе? Почему так странно проверяется близость к двери в Update? Проверяли её работу?

Comment: 1)да, задается   2)да, проверял, у меня так же и ловушки работают, только у них радиус 0.04f

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код с телепортацией по клавише.

Comment: добавил, это просто 2 if'а

Comment: Может вы задаёте всем дверям одну ссылку на Transform другой двери?

Comment: у первой двери ссылка на вторую, у второй на первую

Comment: Что за doortip?

Comment: Попробуйте поменять  `plr.position = linkeddoor.position;` и `character.entered = false;` местами.
А ещё я не вижу проверку по canenter.

Comment: doortip это подсказка "нажмите E чтобы войти". Проверка по canenter в скрипте персонажа

Answer (score 0):

Коллайдер должен быть триггером.

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Collider))]

public class Door : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] private Door _linkDoor;
    private Player _player;

    private void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
            TransferPlayer();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other) {
        Player Player = GetComponent<Player>();
        if (Player != null)
            PlayerEnter(Player);
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit (Collider other) {
        Player Player = GetComponent<Player>();
        if (Player != null)
            PlayerExit();
    }
    
    private void PlayerEnter (Player player) {
        _player = player;
        SetTipEnable(true);
    }

    private void PlayerExit () {
        _player = null;
        SetTipEnable(false);
    }

    private void TransferPlayer () {
        if (_player != null && _linkDoor != null) {
            //...
            PlayerExit();
        }
    }

    private void SetTipEnable (bool enable) {
        //...
    }
}
```